# WCF services with BasicAuthentication over https 400 bad request / 409 conflict?

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl

Been working at this all day and just can't figure out what's wrong with my web.config file for my WCF services over https.  The trace logs only say the following:

**Failed to lookup a channel to receive an incoming message. Either the endpoint or the SOAP action was not found.**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <!--SERVICES-->
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
      <endToEndTracing activityTracing="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" name="WCF.MyOwnMed.com.iosService1">
        <endpoint address="ios" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="thisBasicHTTPBinding"
          name="endpointService1" contract="WCF.MyOwnMed.com.iosIService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>


    <!--BINDINGS-->
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="thisBasicHTTPBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000" maxBufferPoolSize="5000000">
        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="5000000" />
        <security mode="Transport"> 
             <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" /> 
        </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>



    <!--BEHAVIORS -->
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>



    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

when I use WCFStorm to test the services, I get a list of all my methods.  When I try most methods, I get:

```
-<GetAllDiseases>
-<MethodParameters>
-<WebException>
 <Status>ProtocolError</Status>
 <Response>System.Net.HttpWebResponse</Response>
 <Message>The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.</Message>
-<Data>
 <KeysAndValues attr0="KeyValuePairArray"isNull="false"/>
 </Data>
 <InnerException isNull="true"/>
 <TargetSite>System.Net.WebResponse GetResponse()</TargetSite>
 <StackTrace>at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)</StackTrace>
 <HelpLink isNull="true"/>
 <Source>System</Source>
 <HResult>-2146233079</HResult>
 </WebException>
 </MethodParameters>
 </GetAllDiseases>
```

and here is the trace event I get when trying to run a method...

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>262155</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-11-05T23:15:05.6916772Z"/>
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel"/>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{2c51b91c-3b2b-4fc4-a189-d1e7b72f4034}"/>
    <Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="3020" ThreadID="7"/>
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>WEB1</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
          <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelMessageReceiveFailed.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>Failed to lookup a channel to receive an incoming message. Either the endpoint or the SOAP action was not found.</Description>
          <AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-9-130281664299064415</AppDomain>
          <Source>System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager/33099709</Source>
          <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/StringTraceRecord">
            <IsRecycling>False</IsRecycling>
          </ExtendedData>
        </TraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

**UPDATE - something I've noticed, my WSDL file, located here: 
https://wcf.myownmed.com/iosService1.svc?wsdl

uses "http" in all the "soapAction" properties, could this be what's effecting this?  How do these get generated?  http URIs will not work with this service...

Comment: Is the service hosted in IIS? The settings suggest that you have a certificate to authenticate the client to the service, is that true? What is the URL you are testing?

Comment: https://wcf.myownmed.com/iosService1.svc

Comment: Yes, hosted on a server with IIS and there is a real certificate installed.

Comment: The certificate is on the server only? Try to remove the `<message>` element from `<security>` element. The way you have it set up, the web server is expecting the client to identify itself with a client certificate. You have a ssl certificate used to identify the server to the client.

Comment: Also is the IIS configured to allow basic authentication?

Comment: OK, changed it to <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
          </security>, still same thing.  I have left basic authentication out until my iOS developer is ready to integrate authentication into her app.